# Circumcenter - Inside or Outside The Cyclic Quadrilateral

Tags: geometry

I was doing a doing a geometry problem in which three sides of a cyclic quadrilateral are given to be $200$, and the radius of its circumcircle is $200 \sqrt{2}$. The problem asks for the length of the fourth side.

Now, I solved the problem but got it wrong because in my diagram I assumed that the circumcenter of the quadrilateral was inside of it. However, the solution depends on a diagram in which the circumcenter is outside the quadrilateral.

This made me think about how we can know when a circumcenter is inside or outside the cyclic quadrilateral. In this problem, for example, how could we tell that the circumcenter lies outside the cyclic quadrilateral? Is there any giveaway in any relation between the sidelengths and radius?

Comment: Circumcenter refers specifically to a circumscribed circle. See, for example, the Wikipedia article at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_quadrilateral. Regarding the *incircle* with a tangential quadrilateral, see this Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangential_quadrilateral.

Comment: Yes I was referring to the circumcenter.

Answer (score 0):

Since the total central angle to the three sides of 200 is less than $180^\circ$, hence the center of the circle will not be in the quadrilateral.

---

More generally, for an $n-$gon, if you look at the $n-1$ shortest sides and the total central angle is less than $180^\circ$, then the center of the circle will not be in the $n-gon$.
Do you see why?

As a corollary, if there are ANY $n-1$ sides where the total central angle is less than $180^\circ$, then the center of the circle will not be in the quadrilateral.
This is what we're essentially applying.